# How do hiring managers view someone auditing a course?

Tags: resume, hiring-process, hiring, employer

I'm a graduate student who is taking a full load and I am considering formally auditing another course in addition. The audited course will show on my transcript but wont have a grade assigned to it.

I'm interested in doing this for two reasons,

1. I'm interested in the subject and I think it would be useful to me.
2. I want to be able to say I have taken a course in the subject.

How will hiring managers view this? Is it a bad thing? Can I still say on my resume that I have had coursework in this area(even if it wasn't for a grade).

Comment: Yes, particularly if I can answer the same questions people who received a grade in it can.

Comment: I understand, to be safe I think I could absolutely say I have had experience with the subject. Given my performance in other courses which are in related areas I assume that the person reading my transcript would see it as at least not outlandish.

Comment: So then taking a class for credit doesn't give experience with it either? Surely there is something between "I am an expert" and "I know nothing about it".

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the course subject matter is relevant to the job area being applied for then I would look upon it favorably. But only really with regards to the first reason you give, having enough drive and interest in an area to audit a course would impress me.

I'd never consider someone who audited a course to have "taken it" however nor would I say that it would count as experience in it and if I saw someone trying to imply otherwise that would give me quite a negative impression of the candidate.

Comment: Why wouldn't it count as experience in the subject?

Comment: @Flourierflux because there is no evidence to suggest that they developed any understanding of the material.

Comment: Is evidence purely derived from a grade?